# Position of "nicht" in the following sentence

Tags: negation

I am trying to learn negation in German language and have run into a bit of trouble.

1. > Siehst du fern?
   > Nein, ich sehe nicht fern.
2. > Siehst du den Stuhl?
   > Ich sehe den Stuhl nicht.

In sentence 1, the noun 'fern' is the object, and 'nicht' follows the direct object. So why isn't it 'Ich sehe fern nicht'?

In sentence 2, the noun 'Stuhl' is the object but it is preceded by definite article 'den'. So why isn't it 'Ich sehe nicht den Stuhl'?

Thank you for your time and help.

Ref: https://resources.german.lsa.umich.edu/grammatik/nicht/

Comment: Welcome to German SE! If *fern* was a noun, it would be **capitalized**! But in fact, there is no noun *Fern*. For the same reason, *Stuhl* in the second sentence must be capitalized (which you didn't). So just by the orthography you can tell that *fern* isn't a noun (and in this case, it isn't even an object). Besides, as already pointed out in the first answer, *Stuhl* isn't the subject, but an object – it's surprising that you assume *fern* to be an object, but *Stuhl* to be the subject!

Comment: @amadeusamadeus: To be fair, *fern* as a separable prefix is rather unusual, and using a single verb *fernsehen* to mean "watch television" sounds odd to English ears; by that logic, listening to the radio would be *fernhören*. But you're right that not paying attention to capitals made a confusing situation even worse. Also, the previous paragraph in the UMich site where the example was taken from already implies that *fern* is part of the verb.

Comment: I thought only proper nouns were capitalized, but just learned that in German all nouns are capitalized! Thank you. Yes, Stuhl is the object, my bad. I have corrected it in the question.

Comment: @RDBury Indeed, I don't think *fernhören* has ever been used, however *fernschreiben* was, e.g. (for telegraphy and the like) and sometimes *fernkopieren*. Besides, there are less common verbs like *fernbedienen*. English, in fact, didn't translate the prefix *tele-* in the former examples, but still created *to teletype* etc., so maybe the single verb would be *to telewatch*. On the other hand, there is *to televise sth.*, which has no literal equivalent in German (there it would be generic *senden* or *übertragen*).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In sentence 1, *fern* is not object. It is part of the separable verb *fernsehen*.

The two parts of *sehe fern* constitute a *sentence bracket*, where *fern* goes to the end of the sentence. Because the last position is occupied by *fern*, *nicht* cannot be at the end, so it immediately precedes *fern*.

In both sentences the rule that *nicht* comes at the end applies, but in the first sentence the rule that the separable prefix comes at the end takes priority, so *nicht* is second-last.

I don't quite understand what you mean by

> In sentence2 the noun stuhl is the subject but it is preceded by definite article 'den'.

*Den* marks the accusative, so it is clear that Stuhl is not the subject but the accusative object.

Comment: I am sorry...I meant to write stuhl is the object. Thank you for the answer. Have to be vary of separable verbs!

Comment: What about "Ist das die Professorin?-Nein, das ist nicht die Professorin." Why isn't ist 'Das ist die Professorin nicht?'

Comment: In "Nein, das ist nicht die Professorin." it's *die Professorin* which is negated, not the entire sentence.

Comment: Isn't 'die Professorin' the object in this sentence?  I am asking because in 'Ich sehe den Stuhl nicht.' the 'nicht' is placed at the end. https://deutsch.lingolia.com/en/grammar/sentence-structure/negation states 'nicht' should precede definite article.

Comment: @GRANZER No, *die Professorin* is a part of the predicate, called *Prädikatsnomen* -- with *sein* being the *Kopula*, the complete predicate is *die Professorin sein*.